# Hibernate Mapping Files Not Found(MappingNotFoundException)

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I followed this tutorial: http://manikandanmv.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/hibernate-basics-simple-example/

This is my file structure
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX3nn.jpg

When I run Java Applet, I get this error

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: src/com/bookstore/bookapp.hbm.xml not found
```

However, I have that file there as you can see it. When I put the file under

```
workspace-windows\226project1\src\com\bookstore
```

I'm still facing this error even then, Can someone help?

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>

<!-- Database connection settings -->
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
<property name="connection.password">rocker123</property>
<property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>

<!-- SQL dialect -->
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

<!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>

<!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

<!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

<mapping resource="src/com/bookstore/bookapp.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your mapping files into src/main/resources. Only .java files belong in src/main/java.

There is  an example project on github showing how to correctly reference XML mapping files from a hibernate.cfg.xml. Please refer to https://github.com/zzantozz/testbed/tree/master/hibernate-with-xml-mappings

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please have a look at my filestructure here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sX3nn.jpg

I have moved my java files to src/main/java and .xml to src/main/resources yet we are getting the same issue.

Please help

Comment: Generate a separate resources folder, right-click it and select Build Path > Use as Source Folder. That way it's on the class path, but you're not mixing it with your Java source files.

Comment: The problem has been solved by doing the following:

1) Move the bookapp.hbm.xml to /src/
2)Modify hibernate.conf.xml 

<mapping resource="src/com/bookstore/bookapp.hbm.xml"/>
to
<mapping resource="src.bookapp.hbm.xml"/>
(using dot instead of /)

This fixed the issue.

I guess hibernate does not play well with /'es

Comment: Java expects every file inside src folder to be of type .java source file. Files such as xml, properties are resources and can be used by configuring them as resource from class path